# How to resize uilabel inside stackview?

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, uistackview

I have uilabel call "sklabel" inside stackview like image below. But sklabel width size is following stavkview size. How to make it's width follow text width?

Should i make something like Stackview -> uiview -> uilabel ?

[image]

Comment: Yes... embed `skLabel` in a (clear background) `UIView`... that view will stretch to fill the width of the of the stack view, and you can constrain the label's size/position however you want.